# environment lacks native support for critical functionality used by the PDF.js library (e.g. ReadableStream and/or Promise.allSettled)

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-5, pdf.js, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am currently working on angular7, and using

```
 "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^3.3.2",
 "pdfjs-dist": "^2.5.207",
 "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.1.6",
 "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.3.4",
```

During opening it on ios 12 it gives error

> "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): UnknownErrorException: The browser/environment lacks native support for critical functionality used by the PDF.js library (e.g. ReadableStream and/or Promise.allSettled); please use an ES5-compatible build instead.(…)"

Answer (score 0):

Good news first: if you're using a contemporary version of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer, you won't see this error message.

The binaries of the PDF viewer ship in two different version: the default build targets modern browsers (i.e. the last two versions of Chrome and Firefox, plus the ESR build of Firefox, and a current version of Safari). If you're using an older browser, the PDF viewer loads the "legacy" build instead. This version has a larger memory footprint and is slower, but it supports a wider range of browsers (but Internet Explorer is not among them).

The error message meant the PDF viewer tried to run the modern build on a browser that doesn't support it. It took a while to get the browser detection right, but by now, it seems to work stable.

In any case, it's a good idea to update to a current version of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer because it's the only version that get updates and bugfixes.